# order JSON Array by value - Python

Tags: python, json, list

I have a JSON Array that looks like this

```
[{'age':1, 'name':'james'}, {'age':3, 'name':'henry'}, {'age':10, 'name':'andrew'}]
```

is it possible to order this by the age of the people so that it goes like this

```
[{'age':10, 'name':'andrew'}, {'age':3, 'name':'henry'}, {'age':1, 'name':'james'}]
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: Why dont you json decode it,arrange the array,encode it again.

Answer (score 0):

```
In [13]: import json

In [14]: l = json.loads('[{"age": 1, "name": "james"}, {"age": 3, "name": "henry"}, {"age": 10, "name": "andrew"}]')

In [15]: json.dumps(sorted(l, key=lambda x: x["age"], reverse=True))
Out[15]: '[{"age": 10, "name": "andrew"}, {"age": 3, "name": "henry"}, {"age": 1, "name": "james"}]'
```